# How can I achieve this effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://www.colorz.fr/#!/en/work/

I love how they show/hide the content based on clicking on the thumbnails, I just can't get how it's actually being done.
A class of 'hidden' that's taken away with javascript onclick wouldn't really be viable since the page would still load the content and if you had many different divs to show/hide it'd cripple the page load time.

I'm sure there's a simple way to achieve this effect, I just can't think how to do it in a 'clean' way.

Comment: Ever heard of ajax? Use firebug under firefox, click one of the thumbnails and look in the console and you will see that the click triggers an ajax request that pulls in the content to be displayed.

Comment: Have you looked at some of the JS frameworks for achieving this? You can look at jquery/yui/mootools...

Comment: The page load time DOES suck very hard on that page. But...the pro way to do it is to load only what you need initially to get the page rendered quickly, then preload stuff in the background. Ajax is largely irrelevant here as html takes very little download time - its the external objects like images that take a long time.

Comment: @chris - If you had a page with lets say 500 images of wich a user may only view one or perhaps none you should still preload everything in the background?

Comment: Of course not. I don't generally assume extremes.

Comment: Is there a framework for achieving this and only loading the content as needed?
Never really used ajax before and I'm not exactly great with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested it's pretty easy to see exactly how they do things. That's one of the benefits of the web. Most of their code is in:

http://www.colorz.fr/wp-content/themes/colorz/clrz_minify_cache/perfjs.js?ver=383f594a00f097065ec9c1ba0fa1fcdb

Scroll down past the optimizied MooTools library and it's all there.